# p-calendar control present in DOM but not shown in UI when using in turbo table

Tags: typescript, primeng, angular11, primeng-turbotable

I am using primeNg version "11.4.5" and turbo table to show/edit records.  I need to use calendar when user edit the row. Therefore I am using `<p-calendar>`. This issue is the control is created in DOM but not seen in UI.

My code:

```
<td>
<p-cellEditor>
    <ng-template pTemplate="input">
        <div fxLayout="row">
            <div fxFlex="85">
                <div class="inline-block">
                    <p-calendar selectionMode="range"
                                  dataType="string" dateFormat="mm/dd/yy"                                      
                                  formControlName="DateRangeCtrl">
                    </p-calendar>
                </div>
            </div>
         </div>
     </ng-template>
     <ng-template pTemplate="output">
         //some values to show
     </ng-template>
 </p-cellEditor>
```

I have already imported CalendarModule in app.module.ts.

Additional:
In console, I was getting error: core.js:6210 ERROR Error: No value accessor for form control with name: 'DateRangeCtrl'. Then I added ngDefaultControl attributes within  . In doing so, error that was on console is gone but still calendar is not visible in UI but present in DOM.

Comment: Where is <form> tag? formControlName need that

Comment: <form [formGroup]="frmCollect"></form> Its in the code and working because for other controls, I am able to get values from fromcontrolname.

Comment: selectionMode="range" and dateFormat="mm/dd/yy" - i don't think they are compatible. In order to help you i personally need more information or stackblitz example